LINQ - Left Join with multiple conditions and Is Null operators
I want to write following sql in linq.
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM ( SELECT A.COL1, MAX (NVL (C.COL2, 0)) COL2
FROM TBL1 A
LEFT JOIN TBL2 C
ON NVL (A.COL4, '') = NVL (C.COL4, NVL (A.COL4, '')) 
AND NVL (A.COL5, '') = NVL (C.COL5, NVL (A.COL5, ''))
AND NVL (A.COL6, '') = NVL (C.COL6,NVL (A.COL6, ''))  

GROUP BY A.COL1)
WHERE COL2 <> 0

I try to write like ;
 var aa = from a in tbl1
              join c in tbl2on a.col4 ?? "" equals c.col4 ?? (a.col4 ?? "") into ps_jointable
              from p in ps_jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new { .. }

I got an "Parantheses can be removed" error in the first condition. After I removed the parantheses I got 'a' is inaccessible due to its protection level
How can I write this sql linq in C#?

"Parantheses can be removed" is an error? That sounds like a linting warning.

join in Linq only allows straight equality predicates with tableRight.SomeColumn equals tableLeft.SomeColumn you can't access columns from the wrong side.

Thanks @Charlieface so how to write that sql in linq?

Linq doesn't support non-equi-joins, or any equi-join which uses columns from both right and left on one side of the equals.
You need to use separate from clauses.
var aa =
  from a in tbl1
  from c in tbl2.Where(c =>
    a.Col4 ?? "" == c.Col4 ?? (a.Col4 ?? "") &&
    a.Col5 ?? "" == c.Col5 ?? (a.Col5 ?? "") &&
    a.Col6 ?? "" == c.Col6 ?? (a.Col6 ?? "") 
  ).DefaultIfEmpty()
  group by a.Col1 into g
  where g.Max(c.Col2 ?? 0) != 0
  select new
  { .. 
  }

Having said that, you'd be advised to do a proper null-equality predicate instead.
  from c in tbl2.Where(c =>
    (a.Col4 == null && b.Col4 == null || a.Col4 == c.Col4) &&
    (a.Col5 == null && b.Col5 == null || a.Col5 == c.Col5) &&
    (a.Col6 == null && b.Col6 == null || a.Col6 == c.Col6) &&
  ).DefaultIfEmpty()

